# рекурсия внутри CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Есть 3 таблицы (возможны синтаксические ошибки, поправьте, у кого есть возможность сейчас проверить верность написания)

```
CREATE TABLE t1
  (id int)
GO
INSERT INTO t1 (id) VALUES (1)
GO

CREATE TABLE t2
  (id int
  ,t1_id int
  ,t3_id int)
GO
INSERT INTO t2 (id,t1_id,t3_id) VALUES
  (1,1,1)
  ,(2,1,1)
GO

CREATE TABLE t3
  (id int
  ,parent int NULL
  ,name varchar(50))
GO
INSERT INTO t3 (id, parent) VALUES
  (1,null, 'node_1')
  (2,null, 'node_2')
  (3,1, 'node_1_1')
  (4,2, 'node_2_1')
```

Изначальная задача была вывести все строки из **t1** (в данном случае это 1 строка). При этом подключить таблицу **t2** и **t3**, чтобы вывести в строку все `t3.name`, которые относятся к `t1.id`. Задача не сложная, строки я объединил через `FOR XML PATH`. Но появилась дополнительная задача, нужен поиск по `t3.id`, причем уходящий вглубь дерева. То есть, если для поиска я задаю `t3.id = 3` я так же должен получить эту единственную строку, что есть в таблице **t1**, потому что этот элемент является наследником узла дерева с `t3.id = 1`. 
Задачу эту я попробовал решить, написав функцию, которая по переданному **t3.id** определит, подходит ли текущий id по условию, но фильтр с этой функцией работает очень медленно (записей много). Поэтому я решил построить запрос так, чтобы по заданному примеру получился такой результат

t1.id / t2.id / t3.id

1 / 1 / 1

1 / 1 / 2

1 / 2 / 1

1 / 2 / 2

в этом случае я смогу легко искать по всей глубине дерева. Осталось придумать, как такой запрос построить. Ну во первых нужна рекурсия. Тут опять есть 2 варианта.

1. Создать функцию, которая по переданному **t3.id** вернет таблицу со всеми дочерними для него **id** и подключить ее через *CROSS APPLY*.
2. Использовать рекурсию прямо в запросе.

Вариант 1 мне не нравится, потому что таблица, возвращаемая функцией не будет индексирована, а значит выборка так же будет медленной.

Вариант 2 я не знаю как осуществить, потому что в *CROSS APPLY* нельзя вставить *WITH* (там ожидается сразу SELECT)

Есть у вас какие то мысли по этому поводу? Или, может, кто нибудь сталкивался и есть готовое решение?

Comment: можете добавить желаемую выдачу в вопрос?

Comment: @4per, она там есть

Comment: там только корневые значения из t3 (1 и 2), а как вы хотите использовать следующие уровни?

Comment: мне пока не понятно: 1) что мешает сделать рекурсивную выборку из t3, а потом результат соединять с остальными таблицами 2) зачем вообще тут CROSS

Comment: @4per, 1) пока ничего не мешает.. я в данный момент так и пытаюсь сделать. Понадеемся на оптимизатор запросов. Записей получится очень много. 2) не CROSS, а CROSS APPLY

Comment: Вы ба свой запрос с cross apply, разумеется работающий на приведенных в примере таблицах написали бы тут. Тогда было бы понятно о чем речь и что надо доработать. Ибо любой with можно написать перед запросом, а в самом запросе использовать его ...

Comment: Есть два вида табличных функций: _inline_ и _multi-statement_. Если используется inline, то нет разницы между использованием функции и прямой подстановкой выражения из функции в запрос (query processor собственно этим же и занимается).

Comment: @Mike, нет рабочих примеров. Нельзя WITH вставить в CROSS APPLY. Нельзя подставить WITH перед запросом, потому что он ищет рекурсию от определенного Id, поэтому в стартовом запросе рекурсии я могу от него оттолкнуться, а что я передам в WITH если поставлю его перед запросом? К тому же текст запроса передается в процедуру для постраничного вывода и запросы, начинающиеся с WITH она просто не принимает.

Comment: ну значит ваша процедура как то на основании полученных параметров сама должна набрать список подходящих id. Я так понимаю в MS SQL функции могут возвращать наборы данных, значит надо сделать функцию, которая список id по дереву получит и вернет как коллекцию (или как это в ms sql зовется). А запрос это уже в таблицу развернет. И причем тут вообще cross apply, на нем свет клином не сошелся, практически любой запрос с cross apply можно переписать без его использования

Comment: И кстати, кто сказал, что с функцией будет медленно ? вы проверяли такой вариант, смотрели план выполнения ? Зачем нужно индексировать данные, возвращаемые функцией если мы среди них искать не будем. Мы будем эти данные искать в другой таблице, а значит индекс должен быть на той таблице где будет поиск, а не на данных функции

Comment: @Mike, нет не должна. Иначе получится, что я с условием всех параметров буду делать основной запрос, и еще аналогичные запросы для каждой рекурсии, а потом все это джойнить... Короче это попахивает. А CROSS APPLY тут не при чем, просто приджойнить можно только таблицу или представление, а в APPLY можно вставить запрос SELECT

Comment: @Mike, я все это для того и делаю, чтобы по результирующему запросу можно было искать. Да, проверил, поиск тормозной

Comment: А почему поиск тормозной, вы изучали план выполнения, смотрели с какой стороны он заходит и почему не использует индексы, или использует и все равно медленно. Если он в принципе данные из функции нормально не воспринимает - тогда with единственный путь (он кстати как раз может построить тот результат, который вы в вопросе показали). А не зная всех ваших нюансов, не видя запроса вам помочь невозможно. Я например бы хотел завернуть весь или часть запроса внутрь with, но я же не знаю что вы в нем используете и какие из этих операций можно писать внутри with

Comment: @Mike, он не использует индексы, потому что их нет! Их нет, потому что рекурсивный запрос мне пришлось запихать в представление, а наложить индексы на рекурсивное представление невозможно

Comment: @Mike, в общем то вопрос отпал. Необходимо создать постоянную промежуточную таблицу. Об этом мой следующий вопрос. вот он http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583369/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82